# Is it possible to run jQuery code as you scroll to an anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have been looking around on SO and google for 20 minutes or so and cannot figure out if there is a jQuery function or a block of code somewhere that does this but what I am trying to due is run various jQuery functions as you scroll down the page. Is this possible, I was thinking there might be a way to use anchors to do this and just run a piece of code when you scroll to each anchor point? Thanks

Comment: Yes it is. Check out the jquery plugin scrollTo here: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var scrollPosition = scrollY || pageYOffset;

  if (scrollPosition > $("#someAnchor").position().top - $(window).height()) {
    alert("run code here");
  }
});
```

As soon as you scroll down to the element with the id "someAnchor", the alert is shown. This is where you can run your code.

[Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate this](http://jsfiddle.net/esBwx/1/).

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery API:

> **.scroll()**
>   Bind an event handler to the "scroll" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

http://api.jquery.com/scroll

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
 console.log("Hi");
});
```